# Sql Triggers Update Tables before they can be referenced

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a Legacy SQL server that is (for the time being) the Master Table (ALL updates will be made to this table and it will update everything else through triggers). We are working on replacing the legacy system with a new system. in the new system, we have split the data into multiple tables.

The legacy system Cannot handle Multiple addresses for the same client (shipping address, billing address, etc.) The problem is the trigger we have on the legacy table is feeding multiple tables on the Core database for our new system and the core tables are feeding the billing database's tables. The Client is entered and then the Address is entered to reference the client.

The billing table has the same setup. when the core client address table is updated, the trigger attempts to insert the record into the Billing Client Address Table. however, the Core Client Table's trigger hasn't inserted into the Billing Client table so the billing address table is trying to reference a client that doesn't yet exist. 
[DatabaseSetup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkKy6.png)

The Transaction that inserted into the Clients table needs committed before the transaction for the client addresses table is started. but only One trigger is coming from the legacy Database.

Thanks!

Comment: Hm... wouldn't it be easier (and better manageable) to call a stored procedure from the master table and then perform the inserts in the required order from within the procedure?

Comment: We did something similar but we put a *messaging* system in the middle. That allowed us to e.g. skip performing work if related data isn't ready yet, with the intention that we'll retry applying an update message multiple times with exponential backoffs and the chances (when everything is working well) that it won't *eventually* be able to do it's work before it gives up on retries was miniscule.

Comment: @tyron78 The Only problem with that is there is a slight chance the Address can be changed on the Core table and that needs to reflect on the Billing Table

Comment: @DominicHemken sure, but this should be manageable ie Procedure as well, shouldn't it? You can pass the old and the new value from within the trigger to the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are a bad choice for replication or propagation. Change all to proper stored procedures an schedule a job that runs every minute. You'll have 1 minute delay but proper integrity.

If that's not an option, modify your addresses trigger to check if the client exists in billing before attempt insert address. If no client in billing table, stored in a temp table. Then extend the trigger that updates the client in billing to check the temp table looking for pending addresses for that specific client after insert the client, insert them correctly in addresses and delete them from temp table.

Comment: I had considered that. The only problem I can see with that is the data needs to be changed the instant the address is updated. If this does not happen there is a chance an incorrect address can be pulled for billing (not likely but still possible). We may have to mitigate that risk if we cant figure out another way to do it.

Comment: @DominicHemken - business users will *always* say that updates across the systems need to be instantly applied. Here, trying to do everything from within triggers is going to *destabilise* the old system, and you'll be fighting issues like this throughout. Make them realise that "instant" very definitely isn't *free*. Often they'll suddenly find that 10 seconds doesn't make a difference (after all, you may have pulled the billing address from the system instants *before* the update ever got applied. You're still going to send stuff out with the wrong address. Only a time machine could fix that

Comment: @espino316 Using a Temp table is a very Good Option. Thanks! (Unfortunately I cannot up vote it Yet)